# Default validation strings MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, localization

How to get all of default (English) validation messages, so I could translate them. I know I can specify resource name in validation attribute, but I just want to know all the messages.

Answer (score 0):

To localize the default error messages in ASP.NET MVC you need to set the following properties in Global.asax Application_Start method,

`ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "MyResources";
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "MyResources";`

Next, you need to create a MyResources.resx resource file and your culture specific resource file MyResources.xx.resx inside App_GlobalResources folder where you can override the following messages:

- PropertyValueInvalid
- FieldMustBeDate
- FieldMustBeNumeric
- PropertyValueRequired